# Request to reopen a question about vocabulary learning

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[How does learning vocabulary through sentences compare to learning with words alone?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/178/is-learning-vocabulary-through-sentences-more-efficient-than-with-words-alone)

The above question was closed as primarily opinion-based. In fact, a great deal of research has been conducted into this very question. This research is reviewed by Paul Nation (probably the most well-known name in second language vocabulary acquisition) in his book *Learning Vocabulary in Another Language* (Cambridge University Press, 2001). On page 298 Nation summarizes:

> There is evidence that the presence of a sentence context can help
>   with making the word form-word meaning association (Laufer and
>   Shmueli, 1997), but there is also an enormous amount of evidence that
>   shows that even without a sentence context large numbers of words can
>   be learned in a short time and retained for a very long time.

I think this information might be useful for the asker of the question and other viewers of the page.

Answer (score 2):

## Update: the question is open as of June 7.