# How can we stir up some activity?

Tags: discussion

As of today, Language Learning receives 23 visits a day on average. Obviously, this site is still in early public beta (so I'm not expecting 10000 visits a day), but 23 is definitely not ideal. What are suggestions that we as a community can put into practice to draw in some new LL members from other SE sites?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that we are, initially at least, less quick to close questions that are perceived as too broad or opinion-based. I referred to one such question on a previous meta post:

[Request to reopen a question about vocabulary learning](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/request-to-reopen-a-question-about-vocabulary-learning)

A while ago there were several questions from the same user about the meanings of words such as *method* and *approach* in the context of language teaching. I thought these were interesting and useful questions, and I started to write an answer based on the definitions given in Richards and Rogers 1986 book *Approaches and Methods in Language Teaching*.

I noticed while constructing the answers that suggestions were made in the comments under the questions that the OP should consult a dictionary, and by the time I was ready to post my answers, the questions had been closed. This has certainly made me less prepared to spend time writing answers in the future.

Comment: My guess is that there are not many users yet with enough rep. to open/close, edit or perform other moderation functions. Unfortunately a lot of this activity will not be visible to other users. The higher rep. users are the ones that need to step up to the plate at this point.

Comment: The question you've linked has already been reopened. Also, it is worth noting that such high close/reopen rates will be prevalent in early public beta, because the scope of the site is not yet set in stone. Closing questions helps the community discover what is off-topic for this website.

Comment: I think that you're correct. Questions are being closed as if this was already a mature site instead of a site trying to climb out of beta. I think putting some effort in early on to salvage questions will help set the tone for what a good on-topic question looks like and save some trouble later. Here's another example that maybe could have been saved by narrowing the focus instead of closing it: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/896/

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the day, you need good questions. It is that simple. And you need a forum that is visible and accessible for anyone wishing to ask something.

So interest in the topic comes first. Without good questions there can't be good answers. Without good answers individual reputation in the site can't be built. This is important since participation improves along with reputation.

Taking a look at Community Promotion ads or other means to advertise the site might also be helpful.

I would suggest reviewing the Area 51 proposal commitment questions originally [*asked*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top), and see if some good questions that haven't been answered yet could be asked now.